# how to specify the input text in openxlsx dataValidation()

Tags: r, openxlsx

The documentation for dataValidation() in the openxlsx package shows a logical for the showInputMsg Argument.  I am wondering how you specify the actual text for the input message.  I have been trying different things with the value argument but I have not had any success.

---Appending Code---

This is the code I was testing with.  The commented sections show the different dataValidation versions I was trying. Note that I tried all combinations of the variables used with "type" and "operator" in scenarios 1 and 2.

Scenario 3 does give a list dropdown (it works just fine) but this is not what I am looking for.  I am specifically looking for the input message in Excel's data validation that functions like a popup balloon when you select a cell.

The arguments in the dataValidation command in openxlsx do not point to a text option to specify the input message but it is interesting that it is has an option (TRUE/FALSE) to show the input message.
Perhaps this is still under development or there is a different command in openxlsx that will do this, though I have not seen one.

As a preemptive note, I am a huge fan of the openxlsx package, and I am aware of the writeComment command.  However, comments will not work for the project I am working on.

```
library(openxlsx)

textdf <- data.frame(value='Test Text')

wb <- createWorkbook()
addWorksheet(wb, "Sheet 1")

writeDataTable(wb, sheet=1, x=iris[1:30, ])
writeDataTable(wb, sheet=1, startCol=10, startRow=1, x=textdf)

# scenario 1 used to text all type options but "list" combined with all operator options pointing to cell for value text
#dataValidation(wb, 1, col=1, rows=5, type="whole", operator='equal', value= "'Sheet 1'!$J$2")

# scenario 2 used to test all type options but "list" combined with all operator options using text string for value
#dataValidation(wb, 1, col=1, rows=5, type="whole", operator='equal', value= "Sample Text")

# scenario 3 used to test type = list
#dataValidation(wb, 1, col=1, rows=5, type="list", value= "'Sheet 1'!$J$2")

openXL(wb)
rm(wb)
```

Comment: Can you show a reproducible example/what you’ve tried?

Comment: I appended code to my post above

Comment: This might not be possible in openxlsx, though you might have a look at [openxlsx2](https://janmarvin.github.io/openxlsx2/reference/wb_add_data_validation.html) for this. I've improved data validation to handle a few more cases and enabled more options.

Comment: Jan, AWESOME, I have tested the input message title and text arguments in add_data_validation on my home computer (an old Windows 8.1 machine with LibreOffice Calc 3.6) and it totally worked!!!  I need to test it out on my work computers next that use Excel.  Since openxlsx2 is only on GitHub I will face some challenges (employer with strict protocols) but I will look for a way to get openxlsx2 on my work systems.  Will openxlsx2 but available on CRAN in the near future? If you want to post this as a solution to my original post I will up-vote it and mark it as solved. Thank you very much!!!

Comment: @WillPhillips, sorry I missed your reply. Yes, a first version of openxlsx2 should be available on CRAN soon (let's keep our fingers crossed, it could even be as early as September). There are still a few things to polish, but I'm quite happy with the current state. As for additional download options, you can check out the r-universe section in the readme.

Comment: Hello Jan, I was able to get it installed on one of my systems at work. Thank you for pointing me toward r-universe.  It works great! I was wondering if I could message you directly apart from this Stack Overflow thread. It pertains to this subject matter (input text in for data validation) but the reason goes a bit deeper.   Is there a way on the openxlsx2 GitHub page? Please advise what would work best for you if you are open to that.